# Sentry Rails Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, sentry

per the [Sentry documentation](https://github.com/dcramer/sentry):

...Sentry is not limited to Python. The primary implementation is in Python, but it contains a full API for sending events from any language, in any application.

There is a gem called 'sentry' however it is a encryption library having to with OpenSSH and totally unrelated.

Is there a Rails Client for hooking to Sentry already or some other comparable technology out there which can be used with Rails?

If not, +1 for a Rails Sentry Client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I write this (last updated May 2015), the [Sentry docs](https://www.getsentry.com/docs/) list clients for Java, JavaScript, Node.js, PHP, Python, and Ruby.

Comment: Hm, I thought that might have been for server side frameworks.  Silly me. Thanks.

Comment: They've since added Rails 3 and 4. They also have a general Ruby client.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hidden, but in the hosted version (dont know if its in the open source version too) you can find information about Ruby and RoR integration on this page:

https://app.getsentry.com/account/projects/**PROJEKCT-SLUG**/docs/

So it looks like they have Ruby support, but dont tell us on there webpage.

EDIT: I found this: https://github.com/coderanger/raven-ruby

Answer (score 0):

When logged in, there is a reference to https://github.com/coderanger/raven-ruby in the docs.